# Search for specific category

Tags: wordpress, search

I am planning a WordPress site and need search results for a specific category of post AND another search box for page category. Is there a way to set up two different search boxes for this?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask this kind of questions

Answer (score 0):

This is do-able using Plugin "http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/"

Try this ..Hope this will work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Category searching post.

You can use plugin name search by category.

Check out: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-by-category/